# Vagrant Provision

Tags: macos, vagrant

I ran `vagrant up` and it asked me to **update box**, so I updated with `vagrant box update` and it keeps showing me this;

[image]

Yes, I updated VirtualBox. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty32' is up to date...
```

keyword is **checking**, the system looks if you have the latest version of the box.

If you did not have, you would get something like (example from wily64 box)

```
==> default: A newer version of the box 'ubuntu/wily64' is available! You currently
==> default: have version '20160105.1.0'. The latest is version '20160706.0.0'. Run
==> default: `vagrant box update` to update.
```

Since you do not see the message about box update, vagrant recognized you have the latest version of the box